# Regex matching the literal value of . when not escaped?

Tags: regex

If I were to have the regex: `/Hello./g` it would match `Hello` even if I didn't escape the `.` Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

`.` in a regular expression matches *any character*.

So `/Hello./g` would not match `Hello`. But it would match `Hello!`, `Hello1` or `Hello.`.

If you want to *only* match `Hello.`, you need to escape the `.`

```
/Hello\./g
```

Comment: @JohnLandon `.` matches any character... including `.` See my updated answer.

Comment: Might want to edit it again... "So `/Hello./g` would not match `Hello`"

Comment: It *doesn't* match `Hello`. But it matches `Hello.`.